# How to extend Parsedown to add a class to table tags

Tags: php, html-parsing, php-extension, parsedown

I want to write an extension for [Parsedown](https://github.com/erusev/parsedown) so that I can add a default class to each of the table tags.  I've found that I can successfully hack the source code by adding lines to assign attributes in the `blockTable` function (around line 870):

```
$Block = array(
        'alignments' => $alignments,
        'identified' => true,
        'element' => array(
                'name' => 'table',
                'handler' => 'elements',
                'attributes' => array(
                        'class' => 'table',
                ),
        ),
);
```

However, if I try to loosely follow the [Change Element Markup extension tutorial](https://github.com/erusev/parsedown/wiki/Tutorial:-Create-Extensions#change-element-markup) I am unsuccessful (perhaps because the table parsing may be an iterative process and the example in the tutorial is a simple string replacement.)

I've tried:

```
class Extension extends Parsedown
{

        protected function blockTable($Line, array $Block = null)
        {
                $Block = parent::blockTable($Line, array $Block = null);

                $Block['table']['attributes']['class'] = 'table';

                return $Block;
        }

}
```

but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not too sure what's wrong with your code, as your code matches mine. I simply added

```
'attributes' => array(
      'class' => 'table table-responsive'
),
```

to identifyTable, on line 850 so that it became

```
        $Block = array(
            'alignments' => $alignments,
            'identified' => true,
            'element' => array(
                'name' => 'table',
                'handler' => 'elements',
                'attributes' => array(
                    'class' => 'table table-responsive',
                ),
            ),
        );
```

which works just fine for me. But that appears to be the same for you, minus table-responsive.

What version are you using?

Comment: Use comments if you are seeking additional information from OP.

Comment: I would but I can't comment just yet. I'm trying to be helpful however I can but am not allowed by the site.

Comment: That's completely understandable. It is discussed many times on meta Stack Overflow. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).

Comment: Copy copy! Thank you

Comment: Just reviewed one of your questions. Now you have enough rep to comment everywhere. Good luck :)

Comment: Hah much appreciate, Raju. Thanks again!

Comment: @Raju Nice move …

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a very old question asked 5 years, 3 month ago, but I came across this answer on a google search, so thought it was worthwhile answering with the code which outputs table class.

```php
class Extension extends Parsedown {

    protected function blockTable($Line, ?array $Block = null)
    {   
        $Block = parent::blockTable($Line, $Block);

        if(is_null($Block)){ return; }

        $Block['element']['attributes']['class'] = 'table table-responsive';
        return $Block;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered exactly the same problem with the symfony demo application.
Finally it turned out that it wasn't parsedown, because the output was cleaned up by the html-sanitizer.
Allowing the class attribute for tables solved the issue.

For symfony 4 demo app add to `config/packages/html_sanitizer.yaml`:

```
html_sanitizer:
  #[...]
  sanitizers:
    default:
      # [...]
      tags:
        table:
          allowed_attributes:
           - "class"
```